# `transp` In Agda

Tags: type-theory, agda, cubical-type-theory

I'm still a bit confused about the `transp` [operator](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/cubical.html#transport) in Agda:

> ```
> transp : ∀ {ℓ} (A : I → Set ℓ) (r : I) (a : A i0) → A i1
> ```

Is found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01170.pdf) paper and I wonder if there is a relation?

> [image]

As far as I understand, the $\mathsf{comp}^i$ operator lets you transport an $n$-dimensional cube along $i$ and if you already know how some of the faces in the resulting $n+1$-dimensional cube should look like, you can specify them.  So for example, $\mathsf{comp}^i A\ [(j=0)\mapsto q\ i]\ (p\ j)$ would only respect $q\ i$ but at $j=1$, the resulting face would not necessarily equal $r\ i$, is that correct?

They also define $\mathsf{transport}^i\ A\ u_0$ as $\mathsf{comp}^i\ A\ []\ u_0$ which I read as composition with no constraints and which looks a little bit like Agda's `transport`:

> ```
> transport : ∀ {ℓ} {A B : Set ℓ} → A ≡ B → A → B
> transport p a = transp (λ i → p i) i0 a
> ```

Could it be that `transp` is something like $\mathsf{comp}^i$ but where all constraints (like $q\ i$ and $r\ i$ in the example above) are constant (in $i$) and $r$ specifies at which faces the constant constraints are introduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\comp}{\mathsf{comp}}$
$\newcommand{\hcomp}{\mathsf{hcomp}}$
$\newcommand{\transp}{\mathsf{transp}}$
$\newcommand{\transport}{\mathsf{transport}}$

Compared to the paper  you're reading, Agda divides $\comp$ into two distinct operations:

1. $\hcomp$ is like $\comp$, but the $A$ parameter is not allowed to vary in $i$. This is "homogeneous composition."
2. $\transp$ is the part of $\comp$ that allows $A$ to vary. It strictly deals with transporting along a path between types.

If you put these two components together, you can regain $\comp$ (by transporting things and doing the composition part in a homogeneous context), but it has been divided into orthogonal pieces that are easier to manage individually (although I don't have the expertise to explain exactly *what* about it is easier).

There is one important difference between $\transp$ and the $\transport$ defined in the paper you're reading (and in Agda). $\transp$ has the extra second argument $φ$, which specifies when it's allowed to reduce away. The side condition required is that when $φ$ holds, $A$ is constant in $i$. In that case, we have that $\transp\ A\ φ\ x = x$. So, $\transp$ doesn't strictly correspond to an empty $\comp$, but rather to something like:

$$\comp^i A\ [φ \mapsto u_0]\ u_0$$

which only makes sense when $A$ is the type of $u_0$ (which cannot depend on $i$) whenever $φ$ holds. Then $\transport$ is defined with $φ = 0$, which reduces to an empty $\comp$.